# Tracking the "share" funnel…

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, share

After checking SO threads and didn’t find an answer through there: 
I wanted to know is it possible to track a share funnel by user?

Example - Let's say I'm sharing  postA(me)>>my friend(john) shares my post>>his girl friend(shila) shares too>>>and then her friend(ronda) shares…

Can I see: postA Shares: me>jhon>shila>ronda?
Thanks for all your help and answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can track a Share form your application to the first user's timeline, but beyond that you won't be able to track it. The API doesn't allow you to see reshares of posts (yet), so there is no way to follow the share along to the final user / share.

Comment: "The API doesn't allow you to see reshares of posts (yet)" can you explain the "(yet)" is this something that would be possible in the near future?

Comment: I say "yet" because facebook could be working on tracking this, as I know it's one of the top requested features by Preferred Marketing Developers.